# Whether method cancel() in java.util.concurrent.Future should be blocking?

Tags: java, concurrency, future, cancellation

I'm trying to implement `Future<>` interface in my project. But it looks like documentation is a little bit vague for it.

From [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) we can deduce:

1. Method cancel() does not throw exceptions like InterruptedException or ExecutionException. Moreover it has no the variant with timeout. So it looks like, it should NOT be blocking.
2. Documentation says

   > After this method returns, subsequent calls to isDone() 
   >   will always return true.

   but

   > boolean isDone()
   >   Returns true if this task completed.

   So if we run cancel() while the task is processing and cannot be canceled, this method should wait until the task is finished. Which contradicts with 1.
3. The return value of cancel() described as

   > Returns: false if the task could not be cancelled, typically because it has already completed normally; true otherwise

   So, if the task is running and potentially can be cancelled but not at this exact moment, we should return true (we cannot state that it could not be cancelled) or wait (but it contradicts 1).
4. But there is also a statement

   > Subsequent calls to isCancelled() will always return true if this method returned true.

   but

   > boolean isCancelled()
   >   Returns true if this task was cancelled before it completed normally.

   Which contradicts 3 in case when we run cancel() when the task is running and it cannot be said whether the task could be cancelled or not (because cancel() should return true in that case, but isCancelled() should return false).

It looks like this API have been delevoped long time ago and such inconsistences should not appear in the docs. But there are there. Do I understand something incorrectly?

Comment: "So if we run cancel() while the task is processing and cannot be canceled, this method should wait until the task is finished": *non sequitur.* The actual documented behaviour depends strongly on the value of the `mayInterruptIfRunning` parameter, which you haven't even considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I understand something incorrectly?

I believe so. `Future` is not a job control API; it is an abstraction over the concept of a value which may not yet have been computed. By cancelling a `Future` you simply waive your interest in that value; the rest is up to implementation detail.

As a consequence, `Future` is not strongly coupled to the computation which will eventually produce its result. If you invoke `cancel` and it returns `true`, you have moved the `Future` to its final, unchangeable state: that of a cancelled `Future`, which will never produce its value. The underlying computation task may or may not go on for an indeterminate amount of time; you have *no control* over that through the `Future`'s API.

Comment: Interesting interpretation. But what about `isDone() Returns true if this task completed.` in item 2? And other "completed" statements in documentaion? We have statements like "task is completed", and not like "future is closed". It a little bit contradicts with your interpretation.

Comment: But that's just phrasing; "task completed" means that the future's state is now final. The documentation may have aimed for more separation of the task and its result, but the API does indeed keep that separation consistently.

Answer (score 2):

I read it as "isCancelled() returns true after cancel() returned true" and I cannot see any inconsistences