# Does Netty violate the contract of Future.cancel(...) method?

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty, future, cancellation

According the contract from method `java.util.concurrent.Future#cancel` :

> After this method returns, subsequent calls to isDone will always
>   return true.

Netty's Future interface extends it:

```
public interface Future<V> extends java.util.concurrent.Future<V>
```

So Netty should follow the contract. But in fact Netty does not. You can run this sample code:

```
import io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor;
import io.netty.util.concurrent.Promise;

public class DefaultPromiseIsDoneTest {

    private final Promise<?> defaultPromise = GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE.newPromise();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DefaultPromiseIsDoneTest main = new DefaultPromiseIsDoneTest();
        main.isDoneTest();
    }

    private void isDoneTest() {
        defaultPromise.setUncancellable();
        defaultPromise.cancel(false);
        boolean isDone = defaultPromise.isDone();
        System.out.println(isDone);
    }
}
```

The console should print:

> true

But in fact it print:

> false

The following methods also violate the contract:

```
io.netty.channel.group.VoidChannelGroupFuture#isDone
io.netty.channel.VoidChannelPromise#isDone
```

I already created an issue on github: [issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7712)

But I still want to discuss this here in stackoverflow, because I think this is a pretty fundamental design decision for `cancel` & `isDone` methods of `Future` interface.

There are also some related topics:

[Future cancel method documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140463/future-cancel-method-documentation)

[Whether method cancel() in java.util.concurrent.Future shoud be blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691081/whether-method-cancel-in-java-util-concurrent-future-shoud-be-blocking)

By the way, I am a fan of Netty :)

Comment: Interesting that `cancel()` is specified that way. Seems pretty counterintuitive that `isDone()` returns true if it didn't complete and wasn't cancelled.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, but it is a contract made by Java, and also can be explained reasonable, refer the answer from @

Marko Topolnik : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691081/whether-method-cancel-in-java-util-concurrent-future-shoud-be-blocking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netty confirmed this issue, please refer [issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7712) .

I think this contract is very possible be wrongly implemented in other Java async frameworks. Because it is really a counterintuitive contract when we first read it.